# Which lambda is cv.glmnet solving for?

Tags: regression, lasso, ridge-regression, glmnet

This is my understanding of glmnet:

if OLS is minimizing RSS, where

$ RSS = \sum(y-\beta x)^2 $

I believe glmnet is minimizing:

$ RSS - \sum(\alpha |\beta_j| + (1-\alpha) \beta_j^2) $
where $\alpha=\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2) $

$\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ come from lasso and ridge regression, but I'm confused if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 $ such that `cv.glmnet` in glmnet package of R is solving for a single variable (along the whole path) $\lambda$? But then $\alpha = 0.5$ always.

If $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 $, is the glmnet penalty equivalent to $RSS - \lambda |\beta| - \lambda \beta^2 $

I've read through Hastie et al. 2009 Elements of Statistical Learning and Zou and Hastie 2005 so now I'm trying to get some clarification on the lambdas and alpha. Thanks

EDIT:

I found this to be a useful formulation in Friedman et al (2010) Regularization Paths for Generalized Linear Models via Coordinate Descent.

$$
1/2N * \sum (y_i - \beta_0 - X\beta)^2 + \lambda P_\alpha (\beta)
$$
where
$$
P_\alpha (\beta) = \sum (1/2 (1-\alpha) \beta_j^2 + \alpha |\beta_j|)
$$
I thought it provided some intuition how lambda and alpha exist together.

Comment: Relevant: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67736/equivalence-between-elastic-net-formulations?rq=1

Comment: relevant and helpful, but I still don't understand how a single $\lambda$ comes into the picture when the penalty is formulated with $\alpha$

Comment: You haven't correctly given the penalty: the entire term must be multiplied by a second independent parameter, called "$\lambda$" in the documentation.  It functions like the $\lambda$ in your edit (and is directly proportional to it).   *This lambda has nothing to do with your $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.*  `cv.glmnet` helps you find $\lambda$, but you have to specify $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\alpha=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} \text{and } 1-\alpha=\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$. And  because $\lambda_i\ge0,$ it should be clear that $\alpha\in[0,1].$ So in glmnet, $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$, and each penalty has a coefficient that is either $\alpha(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ or $(1-\alpha)(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$.

But treating $\alpha$ independently of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ is convenient as a conceptual model because it controls how much of a ridge and lasso penalty is applied, with either extreme arising as a special case. And you can make a model "more lasso" or "more ridge" by adjusting $\alpha$ without having to worry about how to adjust $\lambda_i$ relative to the size of $\lambda_j, j\neq i$. That is, treated separately, $\alpha$ controls the range of elastic net compositions on a continuum of ridge to lasso, while $\lambda$ controls the overall magnitude of the penalty. The two can be thought of as distinct model hyper-parameters. The method with two lambdas links the two penalties.

And if both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are 0, that *should* correspond to no penalty, but the fraction $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}=\frac{0}{0}$ is unsightly and indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate your 3rd sentence? how did you get to $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ ?

Comment: That's just the definition/convention that glmnet uses.

Comment: ok. and when you said "α controls the range of elastic net compositions on a continuum of ridge to lasso, while λ controls the overall magnitude of the penalty.", doesn't $\alpha$ scale $\lambda$ therefore also controlling the magnitude of the penalty?

Comment: The *total* magnitude $\lambda$ isn't changed by $\alpha$. $\alpha$ just changes how much penalty is applied to lasso and how much penalty is applied to ridge. Because it's a convex combination, total penalty remains constant even as you change $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is 0 or 1, you're doing either lasso or ridge regression because the penalty to one is 0.

Comment: going to have to read up on how L1 vs L2 differ but thanks for the explanations.

Comment: This is discussed in the archives but the biggest difference is that lasso will often zero coefficients out, effectively eliminating them, while ridge will just decrease coefficients in absolute value.

Comment: Yeah I've read that, but I meant mathematically. why can $\lambda \beta$ force coefs to zero but $\lambda \beta^2$ not?

Comment: That's addressed in this thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74542/why-does-the-lasso-provide-variable-selection

Comment: edited my question to include the formulation I found in Friedman et al 2010. I was still struggling for a layman's explanation why there are only 2 parameters instead of 3. I think this formulation elucidates your point. whats the difference between $\beta$ and $\beta_j$ in this case?

Comment: It's not clear to me where you'd like additional explanation. Since this thread has an accepted answer, it's probably best to ask a new question where you lay out clearly what you know and what you'd like to know.

Comment: @Dominik In your first equation, \beta is a vector. In the penalty equations, you're summing up elements of \beta. So each \beta_j is an element of \beta indexed by j. Is that your question?

Comment: Basically.  I think I was just confused that the regularization was simply a summation from the looks of it

Answer (score 1):

Just to add: From the help file of glmnet, we read:

*Note that cv.glmnet does NOT search for values for alpha. A specific value should be supplied, else alpha=1 is assumed by default. If users would like to cross-validate alpha as well, they should call cv.glmnet with a pre-computed vector foldid, and then use this same fold vector in separate calls to cv.glmnet with different values of alpha*

This shows that glmnet doesn't cross validate over $\alpha$, so that the cross validation is just one-dimensional, as I think you suspect.