# Why cant Ridge Regression benift from negative lamda?

Tags: ridge-regression

in Rigid regression, we generally set a positive Lambda for regularization to get a less Residual. Why cant we have a negative Lambda in a regularization if we can benefit from it?

[image]

Comment: We do not set a positive $\lambda$ to get smaller residuals; any positive $\lambda$ will produce larger residuals than setting $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: Also see [understanding negative ridge regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331264/understanding-negative-ridge-regression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two (equivalent) formulations of ridge regression (I mention both because I'm not sure which version you're referring to). If $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is the design matrix and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the target vector, then the two formulations are the following ($\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the $L^2$ norm).

1. The constrained optimization form:
   $$
     \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{\text{ridge}} = \operatorname*{arg\,min}_{\substack{\boldsymbol{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^p \\ \|\boldsymbol{\theta}\|_2 \leq \lambda}} \left\|\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\theta} - \mathbf{y}\right\|_2^2.
     $$
   Here, if $\lambda < 0$, then the constraint $\|\boldsymbol{\theta}\|_2 \leq \lambda$ never holds, so the optimization problem is ill-defined.
2. The Lagrangian form:
   $$
     \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{\text{ridge}} = \operatorname*{arg\,min}_{\boldsymbol{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^p} \left( \left\|\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\theta} - \mathbf{y}\right\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\boldsymbol{\theta}\|_2^2\right)
     $$
   (this $\lambda$ is not the same as the $\lambda$ in the first formulation, but [they are related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4371/97872)). Here, if $\lambda < 0$, then the optimization problem encourages the $L^2$ norm of the vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ to get as large as possible, which goes against the point of regularization.

Thus, in both formulations of ridge regressions, choosing a negative $\lambda$ leads to undesirable results.

Comment: In the lagrangian form with negative $\lambda$, there is no minimum because the norm of $\theta$ can grow without bound. But, apparently people *have* used variants of 'negative ridge regression' (e.g. the paper referenced in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331264/understanding-negative-ridge-regression))

Comment: @user20160 interesting! I hadn't heard of negative ridge regression, thanks for the link!